# Extending Django's User model with a OneToOneField: appropriate post_save signals when not every User is a CustomUser

Tags: python, django

I'm interested in [extending the existing `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), using a `post_save` method to update the model as

```
class LucyGuide(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I'm following https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone, but there is a difference in my use case: every `LucyGuide` should have an associated `User`, but not every `User` is a `LucyGuide`.

If I were to simply 'transcribe' the code from that example, I believe my receivers would look like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_lucy_guide(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        LucyGuide.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_lucy_guide(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.lucyguide.save()
```

As I understand it, however, the first method makes every `User` a `LucyGuide`, which is not what I want. Further, the second method would not always work since not every `User` has a `lucyguide`. Would I adapt this example as follows?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_lucy_guide(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, 'lucyguide'):
        instance.lucyguide.save()
```

**Update**

In particular, I'm trying to understand how to apply the following quote from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

> These profile models are not special in any way - they are just Django models that happen to have a one-to-one link with a user model. As such, they aren’t auto created when a user is created, but a `django.db.models.signals.post_save` could be used to create or update related models as appropriate.

I've noticed that this simple test (which uses `factory_boy` test fixtures) already passes without any `post_save` signals:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from lucy_web.test_factories import UserFactory, LucyGuideFactory


class LucyGuideTest(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        user = UserFactory()
        lucy_guide = LucyGuideFactory(user=user)

        user.first_name = "Andrea"
        user.save()

        self.assertEqual(lucy_guide.user.first_name, "Andrea")
```

So what exactly would be the purpose of the second `post_save` receiver in the blog post? Is there a test that illustrates how this is useful?

Comment: So your post_save signal is sent by User model, As far as I know User model has only 5 fields and luvcyguide is not one of them. If you have a condition based on these five fields or the object is already created then you are in correct direction. A condition will certainly work you have to decide what you want to base your condition upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to create a `LucyGuide` for every `User`, then you don't need the `create_user_lucy_guide` signal.

The blog post says that the second signal is used so that you don't have to call `profile.save()`. The example it gives is:

```
def update_profile(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.profile.bio = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...'
    user.save()
```

Personally I don't like this. It would be more explicit to remove the second `save_user_lucy_guide` signal and just call `profile.save()` when you want to update the `profile`. Then you don't have to worry about adding `if hasattr(user, lucyguide)` checks to the signal to prevent errors when the `lucyguide` does not exist.